# Bean not found spring-saml

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security, spring-saml

I am having a problem with my spring configuration with spring-saml 1.0.2-RELEASE. This is the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean' defined in file [C:\mypath\myBean.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Map]: : Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter] for bean with name 'metadataGeneratorFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/samlSecurityContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter] for bean with name 'metadataGeneratorFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/samlSecurityContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:738) ~[spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
...
```

As far as I can see, I could not find the bean MetadataGeneratorFilter, which is defined in this way:

application.context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="smc.services.*;smc.repositories.*"/>

<import resource="samlSecurityContext.xml"/>
...
```

samlSecurityContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>


<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="extendedMetadata">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
...
```

I took the example from the sample project, but I am not sure about compatibility with my versions of Spring. This is my pom.xml:

```
    <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My IDE says "There is no bean defined in that package" referring to org.springframework.security.saml... so I am pretty sure that the problem is related with some spring configuration in my side, but, sorry, I could not figure out which is wrong. Any clue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thumb rule: check the last part in bean creation error. This one says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter` ; so is class `MetadataGeneratorFilter` in your class path? (maybe a dependency issue)

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because I added the dependency in the pom, but I didn't add the jar in my classpath. I fixed it adding the jar in my lib folder, and setting the scope as *system* in the pom, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${smc.lib.path}/spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to [Abhishek Bhatia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1398531/abhishek-bhatia) !